# How to like a public status by a facebook user from another user via Graph API and Access Token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I tried `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` with `user_likes`, `friends_likes`, `publish_stream` and `read_stream` permissions

But still I can't LIKE whatever public status I choose by FB Graph API,

It just RETURNS (An Empty Array) :

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? although after searching a lot I seen that peoples use the URL shown above with preferably PHP SDK to like

Currently I'm trying it with just `HTTPS` `GET` request, I have enough knowledge of PHP SDK, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create likes you should issue `POST` request or specify `method` parameter equal to `post`

Answer (score -1):

You did not add method=post?token_access"........